# Is there a portable container in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a portable container, a carriable chest if you'd like. Something where I can put items in, but which I can put in my inventory itself.

I don't need to be able to access items in the container while it is in my inventory (forcing a multi-level menu instead of the current two-level).

This would facilitate handing stuff over to my follower and taking it back :)

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists, but if that is the case, i would love to see a mod that does this!

Comment: So... you can't access the stuff in the container while its in an inventory, you'll have to place it on the ground to get stuff out of it?  I don't see how such a container is of any use at all since you are just adding an unnecessary intermediate step.

Comment: yx: I don't *really* need to, but if possible, it sure is nice to have. Why don't I need to: I can carry the container, put it on the ground, put stuff in, and order my minion to 'empty' it. Then I can just take it again.

Comment: Isn't the ordering minion to empty it part more of a hassle than just asking them to show you their inventory?  At that point they behave like a container anyway.

Comment: Oh, but if you give an item to the follower, it has a maximum. If you have the follower take items from the ground/container/... there is no check against the maximum carry weight, and the follower can carry infinite weight. Which I was trying to exploit with this portable container.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Yes. Its name is Lydia.**

There are two "sort of" answers to this question. First off, as noted, you can use followers as portable storage. The other option is to put your uncarriables onto a convenient nearby dead body and then use one of the Raise Zombie line of Conjuration spells, recasting as needed.

Edit: on a closer read, you definitely seem to want option two. You can even tell your follower to loot your "Skeever Suitcase" when you're done with it.

Comment: A follower is indeed a movable (not portable) container, but I can't put a follower in my inventory, nor have it be picked up by anyone else. I do like the Raise Zombie idea, but does it work when you already have a wife/follower/zombie?

Comment: It does work in conjunction with a follower, but you can't have multiple zombies or other summoned creatures following you around without high level Conjuration perks.

Comment: +1 for the second part :D It's a nice combination of gruelsome and efficient :)

Comment: The phrase "Skeever Suitcase" made me laugh out loud

Comment: I know this is kind of late, but there's no need to refer to women as possesions :^)

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m It's just an example jezz

Answer (score 5):

Your best possible outcome for this is a follower. However, if one needed an extra container in their house or something, like one next to the alchemy lab etc. It would be best to reanimate a corpse and let it turn to ashes in the spot you need it in. You can store items in the ash pile because they never disappear.

Answer (score 2):

In the Dragonborn DLC, you can obtain a Dremora Butler as a reward from the Black Book: Untold Legends quest. The butler can be summoned at will and will carry your items until you take them back again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your follower and have them pick up an item, there is no weight limit for them.  However, they can't loot bodies, which means that you'll need to loot everything, drop it, and then have them pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use Shadowmare. When he dies, put your stuff in him. You can raise him as a zombie and he won't turn to ashes or die again.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a companion as portable storage with infinite space. If you go into their commands and tell them to pick something up it wont weigh a thing in their inventory.

Comment: Yes there is a protably storege it is a conpanyion u go into there comands and tell them to pick what ever it is u want them to hold and tell the to do something and click on that item and it wont weigh athing so it is infenit

Comment: except the context of the question is to "***facilitate handing stuff over to my follower***", so using the follower as the storage does not really help, at all.